# Plural subject vs. Singular question

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis, verb-agreement

If the question "Dear school teachers, are you a good student?" correct? I have addressed teachers as plural, whereas the question

Comment: If you are asking the individual teacher a question, I would address it to 'Dear teacher' even if it's being sent to multiple recipients.

Comment: I am asking this to multiple teachers. In that case, how should I write?

Comment: You could resolve it this way. Begin with "Dear Teachers", and then follow with this as a first sentence: I'd like to ask each of you, "Are you a good student?" Or I'd like to ask each of you if you're a good student.